# how can I obtain Google Places API key

Tags: android, api, google-maps, key

I followed many guides but none helped me. I'm developing an Android app that use google maps. I have to obtain some POI with query to google maps and I need a Google Places API key but I don't know how can I obtain this.
All guides that I had read talk about a left side menu from which I can choose the key I nedd but I can't see this menu.
Someone can help me??

Comment: Did you go here https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: @Boss yes but I don't understand what I have to do to obtain the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the guidelines specified here. It is straight forward

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup

Answer (score 0):

Log in with your gmail account at https://console.developers.google.com and create your project. Then you will see the left menu item as "APIs and Auth". You should focus on its sub menu items: "APIs", "Credentials". Good luck